Show the the following equivalence condition for almost surely bounded for a sequence of random variables
So I've been doing some practice exercises on measure theoretic probability. In one of the exercise, I've been ask to show that given a sequence of independent non-negative $X_n$, then
$\mathbb{P}[\text{sup}_nX_n = \infty] = 0$ if and only if $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}[X_n > c]<\infty$ for some $c$.
I've been stuck in both directions. To show ($\implies$), I assume for contradiction that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\mathbb{P}(X_n > c)=\infty$ for every $c$. Then by independence assumption of $X_n$, I can use Borel-Cantelli lemma to conclude that $\mathbb{P}[\bigcap\limits_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup\limits_{k=n}^{\infty}\{\omega\in\Omega:X_k(\omega)>c\}] = 1$, for every $c$. How do I make use of the fact that $\mathbb{P}[\text{sup}_nX_n = \infty] = 0$ to arrive at a contraction here ?
For the ($\leftarrow$) direction, I ran into similar problems after applying Borel-Cantelli.
Any help or insights is deeply appreciated

Hint
\begin{align}
\big\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\,\sup_n X_n(\omega)&=\infty\big\}\\
&=\bigcap_{c=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty\big\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\,X_k(\omega)>c\,\big\}
\end{align}
The outermost intersection here is taken over the natural numbers, but from the fact that\begin{align}c\ge b&\Rightarrow\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty\big\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\,X_k(\omega)>c\,\big\}\\
&\subseteq\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty\big\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\,X_k(\omega)>b\,\big\}\end{align}it follows that\begin{align}&\bigcap_{c\in[1,\infty)}\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty\big\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\,X_k(\omega)>c\,\big\}\\
=& \bigcap_{c=1}^\infty\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty\bigcap_{k=n}^\infty\big\{\omega\in\Omega\,:\,X_k(\omega)>c\,\big\}\ .\end{align}

Can I assume that the outer-most intersection is countable intersection ? (I assume those two sets must be measurable)

Yes, the outermost intersection is taken over the natural numbers, which, being a countable intersection of measurable sets, is measurable.  However, the intersection over all real numbers not less than $1$ is the actually the same set, as I've now noted in my answer.
